# What flooring options are there to make a concrete basement safe(r) for falls while retaining wheelchair accessibility?

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, safety

I have an above ground, sealed, concrete basement that I want to make safer in the event of someone falling, while keeping it easy for someone in a wheelchair to get around. A hopeful side effect will be to brighten up the basement with a cheerier/lighter color.

My initial idea is to get some wood laminate from Costco and lay it down to provide a less detrimental surface. I’m worried that won’t be enough.

How can I improving the safety of this concrete floor while keeping it easy to roll around in a wheelchair?

Comment: There are large rubber mats that will give some cushion from falls while still allowing a wheelchair to move around.  The only problem with them is I have only seen the black ones.  They might come in other colours.  A wood floor would only be slightly softer than cement with no cushion.  Carpet would be soft also and a wheelchair should roll on it also.

Comment: @crip659 those used in commercial gyms come in a range of colours, but probably cost quite a bit. My gym also uses what seems like very heavy duty vinyl, with just a little give in it, in other places. There are also rubber materials meant for outdoors, for play areas.

Comment: @ChrisH   The ones I am familiar with were sold for horse/cow stalls and trailers.   They came in black.   They were tough.  About a buck fifty a sq ft in the 90s, give or take.

Comment: @crip659 gyms use 2 sorts of padded floor-covering  - foam, only slightly tougher than sold for home gyms, and heavy duty rubber. The latter is used where people are likely to drop free weights, and a barbell loaded for a deadlift makes quite an impact. Having rolled heavy but small-wheeled benches over it, that sort could handle a wheelchair.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect these two goals are fundamentally incompatible. The harder the surface, the easier it is to roll a wheelchair on. The softer the surface, the safer it is for falls. Rubber, low pile commercial carpet, or cork are likely reasonable compromises that will give you some of both effects, with rubber being more likely to protect against falls and cork being easier to roll on. You might consider instead a cork or laminate floor overall, with rubber or foam mats where there are likely fall locations. Make sure the mats have smooth transition edges to minimize any trip risk at that point as well.

Comment: The problem with mats is that the edges can become a trip hazard if you have someone who shuffles their feet and isn't expecting them. Wall-to-wall avoids or at least reduces that hazard.

Comment: @keshlam agreed. My experience has been that nursing homes around here use a mix of vinyl flooring in areas that need to be wet, and cork or very low pile commercial carpet in living areas where fall risks are likely, with smooth low transitions between them. Some mats do have transition edges and might work.

Comment: Cork is apparent more durable than I would have expected. Knew someone who had cork flooring and loved it; just sightly resilient underfoot,  reportedly easier to clean than carpet. .. Hmm. I need new floor treatment for the upstairs hall and hadn't considered that option.

Comment: Cork is great, provided you like the look.

Answer (score 1):

Rubber, foam rubber (firm enough for the chair to roll on) or cushioned vinyl are the obvious choices here.

Answer (score 1):

Click-lock pure vinyl.   Hard, flat, easy to roll, doesn't shift.    Perfect for wheel chairs.

Comment: But horrible to fall on.